# How to access categories in Wix Database

Tags: velo

I've been struggling to create a repeater which accesses specific information in my Wix data base. My question is a bit more complex than connecting the repeater to a column.

Rather, I want the repeater to access *types* of data within a column on the database. I have a column in the data base with an id, "category". For illustrative purposes, say the name of the data base is "store". I'm selling two different types of shirts. Some are casual, others formal. "category" has twenty iterations of both "formal" and "casual". If I create a repeater which accesses "category" and displays its text, I'll end up with a repeater forty iterations long. Instead, I want to parse out how many *types* of categories there are (in this case, two: "formal" and "casual") and only to display each category once-- a repeater which is only two iterations long.

(I know Wix has the *ability* of accessing how many *types* of information there are in column "category", I just don't know how to actualize on that ability. I know Wix has this ability because you can create a dynamic item page with a url of name "category". This will create a page for each category in "category". How do I do the same thing but for a repeater?)

Comment: Hey, could you post the code you've tried? As well as your database schema?

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is by using the [Wix Data API Distinct query](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-data/wixdataquery/distinct) and then using the query result as the data for your repeater. This means you would not use the GUI connect to dataset, but the code in the page's IDE. Once the query returns, you can set the [data property of the Repeater](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w/repeater/data) and then use the onItemReady() function for any further manipulation you may need.